# How to mask one ndarray using a another ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have an `items` array which has shape `(n, 3)`, and a `counts` array which has the same shape `(n, 3)`. How can I make every `C` in `items` to have `count = 0` without resorting to loops?

```
items = np.array([['B', 'A', 'C'],
    ['B', 'B', 'C'],
    ['A', 'B', 'A'],
    ['C', 'C', 'C'],
    ['B', 'B', 'B']])

counts = np.array([[1, 3, 2],
    [4, 2, 3],
    [2, 2, 1],
    [3, 2, 1],
    [1, 2, 1]])
```

Expected output:

```
>>> counts
np.array([[1, 3, 0],
    [4, 2, 0],
    [2, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 1]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
counts[items == 'C'] = 0
```

A more explicit way to express it is:

```
c_indices = np.where(items == 'C')
counts[c_indices] = 0
```

Comment: There is no good reason to use `where` for this. It is longer, slower, consumes more memory, and in my opinion less legible. +1 for how to construct the mask though.

Comment: I can't believe it's that simple. Oh well